# Inspecting text in Google Sheets from vlookup without destroying formula, text wrapping, or changing column width to "fit to data"?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, formula, spreadsheet

This has been an issue I've lived with for a really long time, without ever really figuring out a reasonable solution.  I feel like there must be one, however.

I do a lot of spreadsheet preparation for non-technical users. In my current situation, it involves a selection committee that needs to view candidates' submissions.  The problem is, each candidate's responses vary quite a bit in length and size. I am using very basic VLOOKUP's to populate a series of columns so that when a given applicant is chosen from a dropdown menu.

Here is the dilemma, to me it feels like there *must* be a way to view the entire content of a vlookup result WITHOUT having to change row/column width/height to "fit to data" or some arbitrary huge number. For normal text boxes that get cut off, you can just double click the cell, and it neatly displays the entire text content for you. When I try to do this with a vlookup formula, double-clicking just displays the vlookup formula itself.  The only way around this I've found is copying the cell, then doing paste-special and choosing "value only".  But doing this destroys the vlookup formula, requiring a quick control-Z to undo afterwards -- something fine for me, but not something I can't reliably ask my end users to know to do.

***Put succinctly, is there no other way to display/access the entire text content of a cell that is cutoff, if the content is the result of a v or hlookup formula?*** A way, that is, without value pasting over the formula, or having to adjust the column width and/or choose 'wrap text' and changing the row height?

**I was hoping there might be some way to get the contents of the vlookup to appear in something like a tooltip popup if you hover over the cell?** Or some other solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

move your vlookup formula up a row like if its now in B2 and the output of vlookup is 1 column put this in B1:

```
={""; ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(...)))}
```

Comment: You rock. This is easier than an alternate solution I literally just found in the weird wide world of the QUERY function.. which also seems to fix the situation for multiple row vlookups.